# Adding theme JS library in custom module

Tags: theming, javascript

My theme **documention.libraries.yml** file is defined as follows :

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    base:
      styles/dist/styles.css: {}
tocbot:
  js:
    libraries/tocbot/tocbot.js: {}
    js/tocInit.js: {}
  css:
    layout:
      libraries/tocbot/tocbot.css: {}
layout_tweaksLib:
  js:
    js/layout_tweaks.js: {}
```

My custom module implements a custom template which also requires the theme functionality defined in **tocInit.js**. So I'm trying to include the tocbot library from my theme in my module.

I have tried including a dependencies clause in **my_module.libraries.yml** file, resulting in the following :

```
my_module:
  js:
    js/my-module.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - documentation/tocbot
  css:
    component:
      css/my-module.css: {}
```

However, the *tocInit.js* script is not being loaded on the modules' custom template.

I would appreciate some help, please.

Answer (score 0):

From `documentation.libraries.yml`, extend the module's definition of the `my_module` library to include `documentation/tocbot`'s assets using [`libraries-extend`](https://www.drupal.org/node/2497313).

```
# documentation.libraries.yml
libraries-extend:
  my_module/my_module: 
    - documentation/tocbot
```